# How to draw string name of colours in XNA?

Tags: vb.net, colors, xna

I want to  draw string based on the colour value of an object, I thought it would be simple to just draw normally with spritebatch:

```
DrawString(Font, Color.ToString, Vector2, Colour)
```

However, "Color.ToString" returns the RGBA(x, y, z, a) values of the specific colour.
Is there anyway to draw the property name of the RGBA colours (eg: "red") to the screen without having to process through cases and what not to determine the colour via the RGBA values; it would save time and coding space.

Comment: Although it won't solve the question, you mean to write `Color.ToString()`.

Comment: Well I'm writing in VB.Net so no, that is not needed in the language.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict your selection to named color values, you may want to use `System.Drawing.KnownColor` instead.
In any case, if you want the color name for colors that have names, you can use `Color.Name` instead of `Color.ToString()`, but that only works if the color was constructed from a known color and not from RGBA values. If you need to look up a known color name, you could write a function like this and then get the name of the returned color:

```
Public Function FindKnownColor(value As Color) As Color
   For Each known In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(KnownColor))
      Dim compare = Color.FromKnownColor(known)
      If compare.ToArgb() = value.ToArgb() Then Return compare
   Next
   Return value
End Function
```

If you need to optimize that you could create a dictionary where the key is the ToArgb value, and the value is either the color object returned by this function or simply the name property of that color.

Answer (score 0):

In XNA the Color class is not an enumeration, therefore you must use reflection to get all the static property values and their names. The example I provided here creates a static dictionary that maps the Color value to its name. The dictionary will be initialized upon the first use of the class/ToName function.

```vb
' Usage:
' Dim colorName = ColorExtensions.ToName(Color.Red)

Public NotInheritable Class ColorExtensions
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    Private Shared ReadOnly ColorToString As New Dictionary(Of Color, [String])()

    Shared Sub New()
        ' Get all the static properties on the XNA Color type
        Dim properties = GetType(Color).GetProperties(BindingFlags.[Public] Or BindingFlags.[Static])

        ' Loop through all of the properties
        For Each [property] As PropertyInfo In properties
            ' If the property's type is a Color...
            If [property].PropertyType Is GetType(Color) Then
                ' Get the actual color value
                Dim color = DirectCast([property].GetValue(Nothing, Nothing), Color)

                ' We have to actually check that the color has not already been assocaited
                ' Names will always be unique, however, some names map to the same color
                If ColorToString.ContainsKey(color) = False Then
                    ' Associate the color value with the property name
                    ColorToString.Add(color, [property].Name)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function ToName(color As Color) As [String]
        ' The string that stores the color's name
        Dim name As [String] = Nothing

        ' Attempt to get the color name from the dictionary
        If ColorToString.TryGetValue(color, name) Then
            Return name
        End If

        ' Return null since we didn't find it
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Just a side note, I don't natively write in VB.NET so I ran a converter from C# to VB.NET, and then tested it with an VB XNA game to be sure it was working.